# RXJS combineLatest running pipe 7 times for one emit

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I've written a function to combine two firestore collection observables and it's working great, however it's running the map function 7 times for just one result. Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a way to reduce the amount of processing being done?

```js
return combineLatest(
    [
      this.approvedToppings$,
      this.myPendingToppings$
    ],
  ).pipe(
    map(([approved, pending], index) => {
      console.log(index);
      //console.log(pending);
      let toppingDocs = approved.concat(pending);
      //console.log(toppingDocs);
      let toppings: Topping[] = [];
      toppingDocs.forEach((toppingDoc) => {
        toppings.push(this.convertToppingDocToTopping(toppingDoc));
      });
      return toppings as Topping[];
    })
  );
}
```

The console.log at the top of the map runs 7 times for every update, and that doesn't make any sense to me.
Subscribing to each of the input observables shows one result each, and subscribing to the output observable also shows one combined output.

Comment: Could you please include the code of `approvedToppings$` & `myPendingToppings$`?

Comment: They're both angularfire firestore collection().valueChanges();

Comment: So you see the same index 7 times in that log statement?

Comment: @MrkSef Correct. Index 0 * 7 times over after both observables emit at least once, and for each time either of them update after.

Comment: It seems that you're pushing new changes to the firestore collections after getting the result from this `combineLatest` observable, which triggers the `valueChanges` to emit a new value again. Try to check the logic you're doing with this `combineLatest` observable, you may find anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the combineLatest to work only once, you can try using take(1), distinctUntilChanged(), like this;

```
return combineLatest(
    [
      this.approvedToppings$,
      this.myPendingToppings$
    ],
  ).pipe(
    take(1), // Add this line &&
    distinctUntilChanged(), // Add this line too
    map(([approved, pending], index) => {
      console.log(index);
      //console.log(pending);
      let toppingDocs = approved.concat(pending);
      //console.log(toppingDocs);
      let toppings: Topping[] = [];
      toppingDocs.forEach((toppingDoc) => {
        toppings.push(this.convertToppingDocToTopping(toppingDoc));
      });
      return toppings as Topping[];
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but while it does limit the number of times that the log fires, it doesn't actually detect the update to myPendingToppings, so updating the value there fails to reflect in the final Observable.

Comment: That was not in the original question my friend.  Your initial question was to limit the number of times the console prints. Also in your code it's not clear where you are updating the pending observable. Insert more code in either a new post or here to get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Combine latest only emits when it has the value for all of its dependencies. And then it emits again the latest value of each when any of its dependencies emits again.

If those dependencies only emit once, then I think the reason you might be having 7 logs in the console is because you have multiple subscribers to this observable.

Observables by default are cold. Meaning if you have many subscriptions open to that observable, the observable will be created as many times. What happens if you use shareReplay?:

```js
return combineLatest(
    [
      this.approvedToppings$,
      this.myPendingToppings$
    ],
  ).pipe(
    ...,
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

If you want to just get the first value from each, then apply `take(1)` on each dependency.